# Just can't get a virtual device set up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

Specifically: in Android Studio when setting up a virtual device I get the warning "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors is not installed."

Okay, here's what I've tried:

Clicked the link "Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors" and got the following:

```
Preparing "Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gvm-windows_v1_6_0.zip
"Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)" ready.
Installing Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) in C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver
"Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)" complete.
"Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.6.0)" finished.
Parsing C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-30\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\package.xml
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installer
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1062:

The service has not been started.

[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS
[SC] StartService FAILED with error 4294967201.
Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installation failed. To install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors
Done
```

So I go to Github. It advises 2 things:

1 - CPU has virtualization extension and BIOS has NOT disabled the extension.

Went through my entire BIOS, couldn't find any mention of virtualization anywhere. I'm running an AMD Ryzen 7 2700 Eight-Core Processor if that matters.

2 - Hyper-V must be disabled. Refer to this page for more information.

From that page I double-check my current Features, no problem there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOJXa.jpg

And under Windows Security they show a screenshot of a section called "Core Isolation"... which I don't appear to have. My page looks pretty different: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A70nW.jpg

As a last-ditch they advise a little CPUID utility, which I ran from a CMD window with Administrator privileges. The results are... good? I guess? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljihR.jpg

Someone mentioned somewhere that Windows Update can help and hurt this so, whatever, I ran update a few times. It's as updated as it can be. Rebooted, repeated the above. Still no dice.

Oh and no, I'm not running AVG.

Also, following up on advice from other threads:

I changed my Emulated Performance - Graphics to "Software". Doesn't make a difference.

Someone advised editing the .ini of the actual virtual device but that didn't seem to improve things.

Someone else gave a command for making sure the emulator never uses hardware acceleration but... okay that part, full disclosure, I didn't understand the instructions.

Any other advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Tobias' comment, enabling virtualization in the Bios fixed this for me. This meant enabling SVM in my BIOS advanced settings.

Comment: Okay, while I've seen "Virtualization" mentioned several times, this is the first time someone called it SVM. That's new. I've gone into the BIOS in the past and got nowhere, but I clearly wasn't looking for the right thing... so this time happened across a useful article: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1038245

Did that. Boom. EVERYTHING WORKS! Yesss! (been at this for a solid week so forgive my exuberance)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your antivirus has any feature that interacts with virtualization.

Some antivirus programs block certain virtualization functionality to protect against malware. In my case, I had to disable the "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" feature in Avast and restart my PC.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Makes sense but, sadly, I'm just using the Windows anti-virus right now.

Comment: Hmm, if you use windows defender, try to disable device guard and credential guard as described by this link: https://windowsreport.com/disable-credential-guard-windows-10/

Are you sure you have virtualization activated? Please double check it by going into task manager under CPU details and look for virtualization.